# In Xcode, how can I get the instance properties of self in the debug area?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I'm using Xcode 6 (and Swift, but I don't think it really matters in this case) and trying to use breakpoints to debug my iOS application. Specifically, I want to inspect certain properties of the **current instance** of the UIKit object.

So for example, let's say I place a breakpoint inside a view controller. In the debug area, I see `self`. Expanding that gives me the UIKit class I'm working with. Looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the debug area]

What I need is to be able to inspect certain properties on that object. Let's say, for instance, I want to see the `headerReferenceSize` property. I can't find it anywhere. My current theory is that I'm seeing the *class*, not the *instance* of the class? Is that a possibility? If so, is there any way to inspect the instance of, in this case, `FeedFlowLayout`?

I'm able to get by with just using `println` the check the value, or move breakpoints around, but it would be really helpful to inspect all of the properties at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the properties of self in the debug area you've shown. Just scroll down. If that doesn't work for some reason, you can type debug commands into the debug console.

If you want to look at `headerReferenceSize`, type:

```
expr headerReferenceSize
```

Into the debugger console and press enter. It should display the value of that variable on the next line.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have thought, too, but that's not the case. I tried `expr headerReferenceSize` and get `error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'headerReferenceSize' headerReferenceSize ^`

Comment: Strange. How about `expr self. headerReferenceSize`?

Comment: So post the whole scope of the line that's executing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... :/

Comment: Post the whole method that contains the line in question, as well as letting us know what class/struct/enum it's defined in. (Add this to your original question, not as a comment)